# Tidying same ordered data placed in different rows across different columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have made a bulk import that results in df that ends up in a non-tidy fashion. The problem lies on the original databases, and on that end there is nothing I can do.

After import and rotate_df I end up with this

```
x   y   z
1   NA  NA
2   NA  NA
NA  1   NA   
NA  2   NA
NA  NA  1
NA  NA  2
```

Basically, instead a new file's data is being added stackedly, the data of each additional column (after rotate) only starts at +34 rows than the previous one.

Given I can not change the original databases using, is there any jedi trick that allows changing my current df to this?

```
x   y   z
1   1   1
2   2   2
```

As each column has the same information, it would allow for my df to be tidy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting vector mismatch errors, it suggests that some of your "correct" values are also NAs. These could be NULLs in your database, or values that get turned into NA by R because of a type mismatch: make sure you know what it happening and that you're not losing data in the import.

That said, this means you'll probably want to use the other piece of information you have - that the columns are staggered by a reproducible distance.

```
df <-
structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), y = c(NA, NA, 1L, 
2L, NA, NA), z = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), class = "data.frame")

stagger <- 2 # this would be 34 in your real data

df_compact <- as.data.frame(lapply(1:ncol(df), function(i) 
    df[((i-1)*stagger+1) : (i*stagger), i]
))
colnames(df_compact) <- colnames(df)

 df_compact
  x y z
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
```

This will only work correctly if `nrow(df) = stagger * ncol(df)`. If not, you will **not** get an error but all sorts of horrid imputed `NA`s, so **be very careful** and find some other way to validate your data afterwards.

Comment: Indeed your code runs what I wish to reproduce in my df.  However, when I ran it with my df all cells became "NA".

Comment: Actually it seems to have worked! I had to remove the first column with variables' names! But I need to analyze closely the output still!

Comment: If this has solved your problem, feel free to click the checkmark to mark the question as answered. Although this is admittedly a shonky and error-prone solution to a shonky starting problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```r
as.data.frame(lapply(df, na.omit))

#   x y z
# 1 1 1 1
# 2 2 2 2
```

---

**Update:** It seems that all variables do not have the same length after `NA`s are removed. Take the following data as example:

```
x   y   z
1   NA  NA
2   NA  NA
NA  1   NA   
NA  2   NA
NA  NA  1
NA  NA  2
NA  NA  3
```

What's the expected output for it? Keep the `3` like

```
#  x  y  z
#  1  1  1
#  2  2  2
# NA AN  3
```

or discard it

```
#  x  y  z
#  1  1  1
#  2  2  2
```

or use other rules?

Comment: Thanks. It does not work, as "Error in list2DF(lapply(dat_imas_rotate, na.omit)) : 
  all variables should have the same length"

Comment: Darren, I was already running with your data.  "L" are missing when I print(df), maybe because the colums were numeric?  I would expect that it would result in the df of your first post. Thanks

Comment: @jtjtjtjt see my update!

Comment: Keep the 3. Although, I don't expect this issue in my df, as all collumns will likely have the same data, although in different places.  I am having trouble sharing my df, Can I leave in a google drive link for download?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::map_dfc`:

```r
library(purrr)

map_dfc(df, na.omit)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     2     2     2
```

Comment: Thank you. After rotating, it ends with 0 observations.

Comment: With the data that you supply, it seems to work fine. Maybe it would be useful to share with us your real data.